# Changing the value of XML file based on key using Ant

Tags: regex, xml, string, replace, ant

I have a xml snippet like below

```
<bean id="aqConnectionFactoryInitialiser" class="foo.aqjms.spring.OracleAqConnectionFactoryInitialiser">
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.80.182:1234:foo"/>
        <property name="username" value="foo"/>
        <property name="password" value="xAU2oMLjNXU1GrKbcsjvMQ=="/>
    </bean>
```

Using Ant, I only need to  change `value="foo"` to `value="bar"` based on `name="username"` I tried the below snippet but it replaced all  `foo`  occurrences

```
<replace file="E:/vipul/drchanges_testing/testsnippet.xml">     
            <replacefilter token="foo" value="bar" />                           
        </replace>
```

How can I achieve this using Ant?

Answer (score -1):

first you need to select **vlaue="foo"** using this :

```
(?<=name="username")\s+(value=".*?")
```

then replace it by **value="bar"**

[demo for regex](https://regex101.com/r/7uxsB8/1)